# CSS of my java servlet not updating on web when altered

Tags: html, css, servlets

When css of my java servlet page is altered in my dynamic web project in eclipse it is not updating on the browser.

But when the file is saved in another name it is working. Again when it is altered it is not updating on web unless the file name is changed... Looks so strange... Does anybody had experienced the same or it is just me? Any answers?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you restart your web browser or use a different web browser, do you see the changes of the altered CSS?

Comment: No it doesn't change